# VBA cell format that contain a specific percentage value

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that loops through cells to find percentage value and highlight them accordingly on a click of a checkbox.
I have 2 checkboxes - `GreaterThan100`, `LessThan0`.

```vb
Private Sub GreaterThan100_Click()
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As range
    Dim rng As range
    Set rng = range("G3:G30" & lr)
    Dim find As Long
    find = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If GreaterThan100.Value = True Then
    For Each c In rng
        If c >= find Then
          c.Select
          With Selection.Borders
           .Color = vbBlue
           .LineStyle = xlContinuous
           .Weight = xlThick
          End With
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
    For Each c In rng
        If c >= find Then
          c.Select
          With Selection.Borders
           .Color = vbBlack
           .LineStyle = xlNone
           .Weight = xlThin
          End With
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub LessThan0_Click()
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim c As range
    Dim rng As range
    Set rng = range("G3:G30" & lr)
    Dim find As Long
    find = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If LessThan0.Value = True Then
    For Each c In rng
        If c <= find Then
          c.Select
          With Selection.Borders
           .Color = vbBlue
           .LineStyle = xlContinuous
           .Weight = xlThick
          End With
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
    For Each c In rng
        If c <= find Then
          c.Select
          With Selection.Borders
           .Color = vbBlack
           .LineStyle = xlNone
           .Weight = xlThin
          End With
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Both codes work but `LessThan0` is taking significantly longer than `GreaterThan100`. Any suggestions to how to make this run faster? Suggestions on improving both methods would also be helpful!

Comment: You probably should look into [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-change-or-clear-conditional-formats-8a1cc355-b113-41b7-a483-58460332a1af).

Comment: As commented by @GSerg, if you use form control check boxes, may link then to two cells say F1 and F2, the formulas to be added for conditional formatting would be like   `=AND($F$1=FALSE,G3>100)`   `=AND($F$1,G3>100)`  `=AND($F$2=FALSE,G3<0)`  `=AND($F$2,G3<0) `  and apply to Range `G3:G.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, check the final value in **rng** variable after your calculation. In general, if you are considering cell A3 to G30 then your range should be **"A3:G30"**. Statements **lr = range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row** and **Set rng = range("G3:G30" & lr)** give an impression that cell range are not being formed correctly. However my doubt may just be a false alarm, as your requirement is not fully clear with whatever you have described.

Secondly, for concise code, change the following part of your code to one shown below

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If LessThan0.Value = True Then
    For Each c In rng
        If c <= find Then
          c.Select
          With Selection.Borders
           .Color = vbBlue
           .LineStyle = xlContinuous
           .Weight = xlThick
          End With
        End If
    Next c
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
    For Each c In rng
        If c <= find Then
          c.Select
          With Selection.Borders
           .Color = vbBlack
           .LineStyle = xlNone
           .Weight = xlThin
          End With
        End If
    Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
```

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In rng
   If c <= find
     c.Select
     With Selection.Borders
       .Color = IIf(LessThan0.Value = True, vbBlue, vbBlack) 
       .LineStyle = IIf(LessThan0.Value = True, xlContinuous, xlNone) 
       .Weight = IIf(LessThan0.Value = True, xlThick, xlThin)  
     End With
   End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Further, you can merge these two subroutines into one by taking value GreaterThan100.value and LessThan0.value as paraemeters to that single subroutine

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help.